# How to Filter Two Values inside generic List C# unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I don't know what is the better title for this question.
How to get the data from a generic List using compare between two numbers in generic list ? Using Linq or whatever the effective way.

For example :
I have a class database generic list :

```
gems.Add (new gem ("A", 0, 15, 1));
gems.Add (new gem ("B", 16, 46, 2));
gems.Add (new gem ("C", 47, 107, 3));
gems.Add (new gem ("D", 108, 228, 4));
```

With parameter (Code, time1, time2, gemspent)

What i want is select a gemspent or code between two number from gems generic List.

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

Example What i Want :

> when i input 5 => this will get the "A" in List (this 5 is >= 0 && <=
>   15 This is inside A range)
>
> when i input 16 => this will get the "B" in List (this 16 is >= 16 &&
>   <= 46 This inside B range)

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

What i have try so far :

```
Gem = gDatabase.gems.Where (j => {return j.time1 >= 5 && j.time2 <= 5; }).Select (j => j.gemspent).Sum();

return 0;

Gem = gDatabase.gems.FindIndex(j => {return j.time1 >= 15 && j.time2 <= 15; });

return -1;
```

Thanks

Dennis

Comment: What is your _question_? What is wrong with the code you have used so far? Please provide a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you've got so far, along with a clear, detailed explanation of what that code does and what you want it to do instead. Also explain _specifically_ what you are having trouble with.

Comment: Hi @PeterDuniho, Could you see my edit ? See in the dash box : Example what i want, That's what i want. And you can see in Line : What I have try so far, that's explain what i have doing so far and the result is in return 0 and return -1. Is that make a sense ?

Comment: what i have try so far with result return 0 and return -1 mean i can't get the right answer. Because when i input 5 is must be get code "A" or gemspent "1". But what happen is i can't find it in List.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my the solution myself, this just a simple mistake that i make.

Just change the code below :

```
 Gem = gDatabase.gems.Where (j => {return j.time1 >= 5 && j.time2 <= 5; }).Select (j => j.gemspent).Sum();
```

To :

```
 Gem = gDatabase.gems.Where (j => {return 5 >= j.time1 && 5 <= j.time2; }).Select (j => j.gemspent).Sum();
```

and

Just change the code below :

```
 Gem = gDatabase.gems.FindIndex(j => {return j.time1 >= 15 && j.time2 <= 15; });
```

To :

```
 Gem = gDatabase.gems.FindIndex(j => {return 5 >= j.time1 && 5 <= j.time2; });
```

That fix it.